# How to dynamically invoke a highcharts menu item function?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to solve a usability issue in my application, namely that users never seem to know that the context menu has stuff they can do (leading to support questions of 'can I do X?'). I've added buttons that are more visible, just above the chart (this also is easier to deal with when it comes time to do localisation).

So instead of this (after clicking the burger):

[image]

They get this:

[image]

Since highcharts does most of the menuItem functions itself, I don't want to reinvent the wheel and rewrite everything. My first thought was to just do a click on the menu item and hide the burger menu (or potentially call what the click calls), so it is sort of an invisible click. However, I cannot seem to access the .highcharts-menu or .highcharts-menu-item elements dynamically (have tried both with jQuery and native), even though when I inspect the element in Chrome it is available.

I'm working within the load event of the chart, and have tried a 10 second delay (so that all the plot lines are drawn, but the load should be sufficient; it's supposedly called when the chart is drawn, but plotlines do render after, and they shouldn't affect the context menu).

How can it be accessed, or is it intentionally hidden away somehow?

Here is an extremely simplified version, without the delay:

```
Highcharts.theme = {
    chart: {
        events: {
          load: function () {      
              var contextMenu = $('.highcharts-menu');
              console.log(contextMenu);
              //reports nothing
          }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the exporting menu by adding the following to the chart options:

```
exporting:{
    buttons:{
        contextButton: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
},
```

Assign the instance of the chart to a variable:

```
var instance = Highcharts.chart('container', {...
```

Call export actions through the instance variable e.g.:

```
instance.print();
```

## Working code:

```js
var instance = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },
    exporting:{
     buttons:{
       contextButton: {
         enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});

function printChart() { instance.print() ;};
function exportPngChart() { instance.exportChart() ;};
function exportJpegChart() { instance.exportChart({
     type: 'image/jpeg'
    }) ;};
function exportPdfChart() { instance.exportChart({
     type: 'application/pdf'
    }) ;};
function exportSvgChart() { instance.exportChart({
     type: 'image/svg+xml'
    }) ;};
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<button onclick="printChart()">print</button>
<button onclick="exportPngChart()">export png</button>
<button onclick="exportJpegChart()">export jpeg</button>
<button onclick="exportPdfChart()">export pdf</button>
<button onclick="exportSvgChart()">export svg</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Ah brilliant! I implemented this a little differently (without creating an instance). However I needed to download the CSV, which wasn't straightforward. After poking around in the API reference and source code, I got this to work: `instance.downloadCSV(instance.getCSV(true));` https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#toc23

Comment: how to call the above exportPngChart() for multiple charts?
Actually i have two charts in one page, Pie and Bar Charts, if i click Pie charts download button its needs to download PIE, other than Bar.

Comment: @Sathishkumar you can change functions to accept an instance like so `function printChart(instance) { instance.print() ;};` then make 2 instances of charts `var barsInst = Highcharts.chart('container', {...` and  `var pieInst = Highcharts.chart('container', {...`. Then make 2 buttons where you pass an instance you want like so `<button onclick="printChart(barInst)">print bars</button>` and the same for the pie chart

Comment: For completion, I'll point to the [`menuItemDefinitions()` method of the `ts/Extensions/Exporting.ts` file of _highcharts_ source code](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/88d6006/ts/Extensions/Exporting.ts#L1134-L1211) which, contains all the `exportChart()` calls for various file formats and also print+fullscreen code.